# How can I check if a datetime is this week?

Tags: python-datetime

How can I check whether an email was sent this week or not from the datetime parsed from the email? For today we can do:

```
yourdatetime.date() < datetime.today().date()
```

But for a week, first we need to define what a week is, which in our case is all emails since the previous Friday. I should be able to compute it by hand, but trying to see if there are datetime functions I can use to make the code more readable for the next person.

Comment: yourdatetime.weekday()?

Comment: Or the current day minus 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

The best you could get directly would be the use of `strftime` to get the week number. Extract from the page on strftime() and strptime() Behavior :

- `%U` : Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0. Output : 00, 01, ..., 53
- `%W` : Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0. Output : 00, 01, ..., 53

But ... this only accept either monday or sunday as first day of the week, neither friday, nor saturday. If it is not enough, you will have to develop your own algorythm in a dedicated function.